# unable to instantiate component info

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to get a simple 'hello world' to show up in an emulator but I get the error below. I've tried everything from cleaning, adding .jar files, to moving external file up in the order in "Order and Export" and deleting the bin and gen folders and rebuilding. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Please help.

Thanks.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{src.testapp.two/src.testapp.two.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "src.testapp.two.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/src.testapp.two-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/src.testapp.two-1, /system/lib]]
```

Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="src.testapp.two"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
     android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/hello_world" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity Class

```
package testapp.two;

import testapp.two.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
    }
}
```

Comment: where did you put your class?

Comment: try changing package="src.testapp.two  to package="testapp.two"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package name in Manifest and Class should be same in order to run your app.
So, Please change either of the one to make them equal.